# IMPDP remap_schema multiple files

Tags: oracle, oracle-dump

Here is the correct syntax for a single schema IMPDP rename :

> impdp system/**** directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=export_something.dmp
> logfile=imp.log remap_schema=name:newname

How would you import multiple schemas from one export while remapping them? Will this work?

> impdp system/**** directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=export_something.dmp
> logfile=imp.log remap_schema=name:newname,name2:newname2,name3:banana

Comment: According to the [Oracle Database Utilities Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_import.htm), "Multiple `REMAP_SCHEMA` lines can be specified, but the source schema must be different for each one." So this one would seem perfectly valid for me, as long as you meet the requirements.

Comment: I did not try it as I do not have any environment to try it on.
The oracle documentation does talk about it but does not give any example nor hints towards syntax..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried IMPDP REMAP_SCHEMA on a live oracle instance and it works with the above syntax.

You must only keep in mind these things :

-You can't remap the same schema under different names at once (For that impdp it multiple times)

-The schema names have to be in your export (of course)